# simulate a cmd window with input text flash actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an TextInput component and like any text field, it needs to go to 
a new line when they hit enter. And like a command window, it will 
auto fill //the next line with a word, cursor flashing and they type 
in more text and hit enter again. So basically, I would like to specify some of the text, and let them type in more. Then test to see if all of the text is correct.

```
ping_4.text = "";
```

Flashing cursor, no text is visible. They type router

```
stage.focus = ping_4;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown4);
function myKeyDown4(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER && ping_4.text == "router<enable") {
        nextFrame();
    }
}
```

on the next frame,
ping_5.text = "Router A"; 
they see:
Router A 
they add #ping and hit enter:

```
stage.focus = ping_5;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myKeyDown5);
function myKeyDown5(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER && ping_5.text == "Router A #ping") {
        nextFrame();
    }
}
```

This is just sample code since it doesn't actually work. I am using a TextInput field since an Input Text field wont except "<" symbols. Flash CC...

Hope this makes some sense. Thanks in advance!

Comment: And they backspace clearing your text, and get stuck. I say use enter frame events instead of keyboard, and check `text` property of your text fields. Note also, you should process a line of text at newline instead.

Comment: "*Hope this makes some sense.*" not really, no. "*This is just sample code since it doesn't actually work.*" stop doing that please. Writing code that you don't fully understand is a horrible way to explain something. Instead, explain your goal in plain English.

Comment: On other forums a simple explanation did not suffice. And I have to use keyboard because the unix "cmd" window the student will be using works that way. "So basically, I would like to specify some of the text, and let them type in more. Then test to see if all of the text is correct." Is it possible? One request is to set the text to be Protocol []: and they type in between the brackets. Doubt that is possible, but that's what they are asking...

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to do -- show the user a mock command line, have them type in commands of real tools, evaluate the text they entered to see if they entered the correct commands, and move them to the next step when they succeed.  But ... your question doesn't actually contain a question.  What kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: how can I use "text =" and "if text ==" in the same actions window? As a work around I changed how the  file works: